# Seek() function failed

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a problem with seek() function.
When I use media.netStream.seek(x) (with FLV Sound File), Sound is off during 'x' second and after it play again. It is like a pause.

It's strange because I stream 3 Media simulaneous (2 Video Media and 1 Audio Media).
There is no problem with Video media, but with sound media.

For exemple, when I do :
this.m_netStream.seek(time) with time = 5, The 2 video Media switch to the 5th second but Audio Media wait 5 seconds before playing.

Another strange thing : The same code is OK with Flash plugin 10.032 and older. But since V10.1, It's not OK. I always must  downgrade flash plugin version, but it's not properly solution.

I don't know how repair this problem.

Best regards,

Comment: Sounds like a proper bug, have you tried to search in http://bugs.adobe.com/flashplayer/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to manually reduce the buffer size on your audio stream to something small (500ms) when the seek occurs (NetStatus.SEEK), then increase the buffer size after it is full while the audio is already playing.

The issue could simply be that your audio stream has a large buffer (i.e. 30 seconds) that takes 5 seconds to fill before playback begins.

Most of the time, people start with small buffers, then increase them as they fill. That way, your media starts quickly, but slowly fills a larger buffer in the background while you are watching / listening.